# How to find row where one table has NULL values and other has values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a script which will give me distinct rows from table which has NULL value in Table A but for same columns Table B has values.

Scenario: I have 2 Tables: 
Table A and Table B have the same columns

The values in Table A are

```
| ID | Name      | LicenseNo | NationalLicenseNumber |
| 1  | 'ABC,XYZ' |  NULL     | NULL                  |
| 1  | 'CDS,ABD' |  NULL     | NULL                  |
```

Table B has values like :

```
| 1  | 'XYZ ABC' | 1234567   | 976633                |
| 1  | 'ABD CDS' | 4324223   | 304242                |
```

and so on... I want to display the result which shows me value in all columns from both tables. 
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: On what column should table A join to table B?  The IDs you supplied are all "1"s.  Is this intentional?  Also, please clarify "give me distinct rows from table which has NULL value in Table A but for same columns Table B has values" - what *exactly* is it you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try this select:

```
select a.ID,a.Name,a.LicenseNo,a.NationalLicenseNumber,
       b.ID,b.Name,b.LicenseNo,b.NationalLicenseNumber
from TableA a
left outer join TableB b on a.ID=b.ID
where
    ((a.Name is null) and (b.Name is not null))
or  ((a.Name is not null) and (b.Name is null))
    ((a.LicenseNo is null) and (b.LicenseNo is not null))
or  ((a.LicenseNo is not null) and (b.LicenseNo is null))
    ((a.NationalLicenseNumber is null) and (b.NationalLicenseNumber is not null))
or  ((a.NationalLicenseNumber is not null) and (b.NationalLicenseNumber is null))
```

It joins both tables on `ID`, and keeps only the rows where null-ness of the corresponding columns is different.

**EDIT** Replaced `(a.Name is null) <> (b.Name is null)` that causes syntax errors with a longer expression that does not compare booleans.

Comment: My understanding is that, at least in SQL Server 2008, the default setting is that comparisons involving null always return NULL, such that this query won't work. As it is, SQL Server gives me a "Syntax Error near '<'" when I attempt eexecution. Also, this will return the irritating "Expr_1, Expr_2" as column names for TableB without aliasing the columns.

Comment: @XIVSolutions this query does not compare nullable values to each other. Rather, it compares *boolean* values - the results of comparing columns to `null` in "is null" operators.

Comment: Yeah, I had that thought, but it still gives me the syntax error in SSMS. Other than that, once I realized that it was comparing booleans, I almost didn;t post my answer. But when I tried this method, it throws up the previously noted syntax error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, if the syntax issue is simply me missing something (ALWAYS a distinct possibility!), is there an advantage to your approach vs simply RIGHT JOIN-ing on ID, and then settting WHERE criteria such that records in TableA with NULL values in any of the columns are returned (see my answer).

Comment: @XIVSolutions You are right, SQL Server does not let me compare booleans. I replaced the expression with an equivalent that should work.

Comment: So that still leaves me wondering if there is an advantage I am unaware of to the somewhat more verbose approach you propose over the RIGHT JOIN WHERE <columns contain null>. Also, it seems like your solution, as modified, will return rows from either table which contain NULL values, while the OP proposed returning records from one table with NULL values. btw, I am not trying to be argumentative here, just wanting to see if I might be missing something. With 16.1k rep, you obviously know what you're doing . . .

Comment: @XIVSolutions These are not different *approaches*, these are fundamentally different queries that return very different results.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply check if is not null:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_A 
WHERE  Name IS NOT NULL AND LicenseNo IS NOT NULL AND NationalLicenseNumber IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_B
WHERE  Name IS NOT NULL AND LicenseNo IS NOT NULL AND NationalLicenseNumber IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Also, it addresses the issue of the second set of columns with identical nam es returning simply as "Expr_1", "Expr_2", etc by aliasing the columnNames of TableB.
This returns all the rows in TableB (Which, according to your posting, conotain all the proper values) and joins them on the ID field to rows in TableA (Which you say may have rows with NULL values in any of the other fields). This will return records for both tables where the ID's match, and where any one or more of the associated fields in TableA are null.

```
SELECT     
    a.ID, 
    a.Name, 
    a.LicenseNo, 
    a.NationalLicenseNo, 
    b.ID AS b_ID, 
    b.Name AS b_Name, 
    b.LicenseNo AS b_LicenseNo, 
    b.NationalLicenseNo AS b_NationalLicenseNo
FROM         
    TableA AS a RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    TableB AS b ON a.A = b.A
WHERE     
    (a.Name IS NULL) OR
    (a.LicenseNo IS NULL) OR
    (a.NationalLicenseNo IS NULL)
```